# how to check a null value in textbox

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I've been working recently in Xcode. I've used a table view with 4 text boxes, and on a button click i'm checking whether any of the text boxes have a null value if not saving it in a local file.

The code is given below

```
NSString *FName, *LName, *Email, *Pwd;

FName=registerFirstName.text;
LName=registerLastName.text;
Email=registerEmail.text;
Pwd=registerPassword.text;

BOOL fileexists=[[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:storePath];
if(!fileexists)
    [storeManager createFileAtPath:storePath contents:nil attributes:nil];

if (FName !=NULL && LName != NULL && Email != NULL && Pwd != NULL && FName!=@"" && LName!=@"" && Email!=@"" && Pwd!=@"") {

    UIAlertView *missingInfo=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Missing Details" message:@"All Fields Are Necessary" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [missingInfo show];
  } else {
    NSString *fullUserInfo;
    fullUserInfo=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"First Name:\t%@\nLast Name:\t%@\nEmail ID:\t%@\nPassword:\t%@",FName,LName,Email,Pwd];
    [fullUserInfo writeToFile:storePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    UIAlertView *test=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"InfoSaved" message:fullUserInfo delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [test show];
}
```

When I run it in the simulator without entering any values, it did work showing an alert that missing fields. But when I typed some value in the text box and then erased it, if I clicked done to save it, it accepts null value and stores to it which i don't want to happen. Is there anything wrong with my logic in my code, or is there any other function by default in xcode to check for null?.

Comment: You can check the length of string like [str length]; if it returns 0 then it is null Or used nil instead of NULL

Comment: @samfisher `nil` and `NULL` essentially the same.

Comment: I think the condition used in if statement will be == nil, but not != NULL

Comment: use this if ((textView.text == NULL) || [textView.text isEqualToString:@""])

Comment: you should also accept the answer, it adds to your profile.

Comment: @JonathanCichon, u are right. Though, after reading ur comment, i felt that I was drunk when I posted my comment on this post..

Answer (score 3):

```
if (textfieldName.text.length == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Text field empty");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Text field has value");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

comparing to NULL or nil is not going to give you expected result.... for checking whether the string is empty or not,you have to use this...

```
if([Fname isEqualtoString = @""] &&.....)
{
   UIAlertView *missingInfo=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Missing Details" message:@"All Fields Are Necessary" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [missingInfo show];
}
else
{
//put your code here.
}
```

i am sure... this is going to help you a lot... Cheers...

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS application

```
if([_text.stringValue isNotEqualTo:@""]){
    NSLog(@"contains");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"empty");
}
```

EDIT:

For ios:

```
NSString *textString=_text.text;

if(textString==NULL){
    NSLog(@"NULL");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"contains");
}
```

Comment: how to get this property , isNotEqualTo?

Comment: that is an instance method for NSString. And I think you only have downvoted me... can you tell me the reason please....

Comment: can you please explain me , how to use it?

Comment: I am not getting in what sense you are asking 'how to use it' ? If you find any mistake then kindly tell me, otherwise I am giving a link of project that has only this method. http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/view.php?id=5296197&da=y

Comment: You (account name 'rajneesh071') have just tried to access a document in another KeepandShare account 'anoopvaidya'.  To view it you need to ask the owner of the other account to set the Sharing controls to give your KeepandShare user name 'rajneesh071' rights to view the document.

Comment: Brother i don't think that  @Pradeep Ramalingam asking his question for mac platform..

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
if ([myString isEqualtoString:@""])
{

}
else
{

}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if(Fname.length==0)
{
  NSLog(@"null");
}
```

Comment: How is a textField going to equal NSNull?